# What does "hold" mean in "hold accountable"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

Example 1:

> He questions the coherence and purpose of departmental majors, describes programs of study abroad as little more than recreational excursions, criticizes lecturers for their indifference to whether students learn anything, and, in general, **holds** faculty *accountable for* ignoring research about which teaching methods are most effective.

which is from [Bok, D.: Our Underachieving Colleges: A Candid Look at How Much Students Learn and Why They Should Be Learning More. (New Edition) (eBook and Paperback):](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8648.html)

Example 2:

> Public officials can finally be **held** *accountable for* their actions

which is from [accountable definition | English dictionary for learners | Reverso:](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/accountable)

I am not sure what the meanings of **hold** in these two examples are

I look up the dictionary

[16 [transitive] to have a belief or an opinion about somebody/something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hold_1?q=hold)

**hold somebody/something + adv./prep./adj.**

> She is held in high regard by her students (= they have a high opinion of her).

Does it explain the meaning of **hold** in those two examples correctly?

Thanks....

Comment: Did you see definition 17?  "[transitive] (formal) to consider that something is true" "hold somebody/something + adj." *Parents will be held responsible for their children's behaviour*

Comment: Wow, thank you. I didn't see it until now. [definition 17](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hold_1?q=hol) explains perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [idioms](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiom). I do not believe trying to choose a definition of *hold* will be helpful. We must consider the entire expression.

> [hold someone accountable (for something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+accountable)
>   to consider someone responsible for something; to blame something on someone

So in 1., "he" considers faculty responsible for "ignoring research about which teaching methods are most effective".

In 2., presumably, the public can finally consider the public officials responsible for their actions. There is an implication that there will be **consequences** for their past or future actions. So another way to interpret 2. is that that the public will blame the public officials if there are problems, and the public officials will face consequences.

*To hold someone in high regard* is **another** idiom. It means what you wrote: "have a high opinion of her".

Comment: I'm not really sure this is an idiom - you can hold someone accountable, hold them responsible, hold them in high regard, hold someone in contempt, etc.  I think it's just [definition 7a: to think of in a particular way](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold).

Comment: I wasn't sure either. But I found it under idioms on that site. So that is how I reported it. Further, I thought it was much better to understand it as a fixed expression rather than try to decipher what _hold_ means here, at least for "hold accountable". It's like if a learner read "jumped the shark" and asked what does "jumped" mean here, or worse, what does "shark" mean here.

Comment: I forgot to mention references. Both are from different dictionaries. I agree with @probablyme that it is a better way to understand the meaning of a phrase as a whole. For example, **catch 22** is a phrase, looking up the dictionary, there would be a single entry explaining the meaning of it. [Catch-22](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/catch%2022) In some cases, like this one, after knowing the meaning of **accountable** in the context, anaylitical skill would be helpful to understand the meaning of **hold** here.